# Verify installation, print version if already installed otherwise install that package

Tags: python, linux, package

I am creating setup file, where first I check whether particular package already installed or not, if yes then print it's version, otherwise install that package.

consider `nltk`, I am doing like this:

```
nltkv = '{}.'.format(nltk.__version__)
if nltkv == '':
    print "Nltk is not installed, Let's start installing .../n"
    subprocess.call('sudo pip install -U nltk', shell = True)
    #sudo easy_install pip
else:
    print "nltk is already installed, V : /n", nltkv
```

but for this I need to do `import nltk`

so in case, if nltk is not already installed then it gives error on first line:

```
  File "setup.py", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk
ImportError: No module named nltk
```

there are several such packages to be verified and installed. I am using ubuntu and python

Any better approach exist for this?

Comment: You can catch the `ImportError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
import subprocess 
try:
    import nltk
    nltkv = '{}.'.format(nltk.__version__)
    print "nltk is already installed, V : \n", nltkv # mind the escape sequence
except ImportError:
    print "Nltk is not installed, Let's start installing ...\n"
    subprocess.call('sudo pip install -U nltk', shell = True)
    #sudo easy_install pip
except:
    print "Some error occurred!\n"
```